# does CAR_DOCK in android 4.4.4 works for you?

Tags: android

are you able to use your app as a default one in car mode?

i try to turn on car mode and install my app as a main car dock, and it does not work on 4.4.4 nexus 4

code:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_MODE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and the app called in onCreate()

```
private void initCarMode() {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (pref.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.CARMODE_PREF_VALUE, false)) {
        UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);

        if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() != Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR){
            modeChanged = true;

            uiModeManager
            .enableCarMode(UiModeManager.ENABLE_CAR_MODE_GO_CAR_HOME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As usual, define "does not work"

Comment: 'does not work' - my app is runing, cell phone is in car dock mode, i click home button - normal desktop is shown. Expected after clicking home button my app is shown.